# Displaying XY coordinates CSV file but not showing correct location on basemap of ArcMap?

Tags: coordinate-system, arcmap, display

I uploaded a CSV file to ArcMap with longitude and latitude value. The values were obtained from Google Maps and verified in Google Earth.
I used display XY with X(longitude) and Y(latitude) and I used the geographic coordinate system as WGS 1984. The extent of my point feature class created is in decimal degrees (dd).

However, the points do not display in the right location on my base map (imagery from ArcMap). They are showing off the coast of Cyprus while they should be in Lebanon (Cyprus and Lebanon are in the same UTM zone 36N).

I set the data frame's coordinate system the same as my layer (WGS 1984). I tried to project my layer to WGS 1984 auxiliary mercator and another time to UTM Zone 36N using project and define projection tools but they did not give the right output.

How can I fix this?

I have read through similar posted questions and couldn't figure it out.

Here are some sample data points:

[image: Sample data]

Comment: Take a look at this [video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OU8BVAxDDdg) min 15:34.

Comment: Followed the exact steps. Organized my CSV file better and added the data before basemap. Still the data is not showing in the right location.

Comment: Switch your Longitude and Latitude, that should solve the issue. Looks like the axis were reversed. Lat 33.78342, Lon 35.49254 falls in Khalde, Lebanon.

Comment: Please edit your question to add some sample data *as text* not as a screenshot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your longitude should be latitude, here is where 35 degrees **longitude** and 33 degrees **latitude** is in google earth.
[image: here is were 35 degrees **longitude** and 33 degrees **latitude** is in google earth]